# AWS Cloudfront + Load Balancer, try to change domain from load balancer subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I face the same situation, except that my framework is Ruby on Rails 4.2.6 (Ruby version 2.2.4)

- I have do exactly the solution told, but when I try to login, always redirect to root page.(still not logined)

  And I checked server log, login status was 200 success.
- another clue is that when I go to the page which not enable

  `before_action :authenticate_user!`

  everything works fine. (domain not redirect to elb domain)

I think the problem is in the login part, but still not find the exact bug and solution.

How to make ec2 catch the host we expected (**example.com**), not elb host (elb.example.com)

Answer (score 0):

Configure the CloudFront Cache Behavior settings to whitelist the `Host` header for forwarding.  You may also need to whitelist one or more cookies, and possibly query strings.  CloudFront forwards minimal headers by default, and no query parameters or cookies.

As a rule, the more things you forward, the lower your cache hit ratio... but obviously certain things must be forwarded unless the site is entirely static.